# Disable AWS ELB health check

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, healthcheck

Is there a way to disable AWS ELB's health check completely? I use a logger middleware (morgan) to log all requests and it's quite annoying for health check requests to get logged every 5min.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than disabling it completely, have your webserver serve a static HTML page (thus bypassing node entirely) and check that URL. Alternatively, morgan appears to have a `skip` function you can use to exempt certain requests from logging - the ELB sends a particular HTTP user agent string (`ELB-HealthChecker/1.0`, I'd ignore the version number though) you can look for.